# Firefox extension can't installed via registry

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have an own extension, it signed by Mozilla.

I want to install it via registry (described on mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Adding_extensions_using_the_Windows_registry):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions]
"ffinterop@acme.com_signed"="C:\\work\\Foo\\ffinterop@acme.com_signed-2.2.48.41239.xpi"
```

But it can't show up after starting firefox, no message, no error. This extension worked a few weeks ago...

If I have a try with a non-signed version of this extension, firefox shows it as disabled with a warning, it's ok (signing is required). But the signed one is completely dead.

What is the problem?

Comment: What you are doing with your add-on is installing it "side-loaded". The text of ["Unlisted add-ons"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Unlisted_add-ons) implies, but does not actually say, that doing so requires a permission to be set within the signed add-on. The text *implies* that trying to "side-load" an add-on will fail if you do not inform AMO that this is desired when you submit the add-on to them for signing.

Comment: There is no missing permission (run as local admin), but I misspelled the registry key name, it was the problem. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't read the details in the docs... The registry key name and the extension id in the manifest MUST BE the SAME.

> The [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#id) of the extension must be used as the name of the Registry
>   entry.

After fixing the name, the extension installed automatically.